# Unicode based programming language

Tags: unicode, programming-languages

This is a curiosity more than anything: Does there exist a programming language that allows variables, functions, and classes to be named using using Unicode rather than ASCII (except, of course, for special characters such as '+')?  Do any popular languages have support for this?

Also, related to this, if any common language supports Unicode, then is there any way to convert an existing API into a language of the user's own choice?  It seems like it would be helpful to give a programmer the ability to learn an API in their own language.  I imagine downloading a standard API (for instance boost) and then downloading the standard translation mapping and then being able to program in my native language.

Comment: I do not agree that it's helpful to learn an API in your own language. Almost no APIs support this, so you just aswell get your feet wet with the English language right away. Btw, the function names in excel formulas have been translated. This makes it a royal pain in the behind to talk to someone about excel formulas if you are not both using the same language/version.

Comment: Can you name a reasonably modern and professional programming language that *doesn’t*? (PHP doesn’t count as professional :) )

Comment: I doubt this would meaningful use for such a language. Just imagine, you have language where a english user writes "if var greater than 5 then do somefunction()" and the other one writes in german "wenn var größer als 5 dann mache irgendeinefunktion". I don't it's useful to write code where variablenames are chinese. a language has to be equal for everyone and if you want to programm, some english is basically mandatory (I'm german) It makes programming easier for everyone, not for a localy limited audience

Comment: @klausbyskov: I remember when I saw a formula in excel in my own language, and I had very much trouble understanding it since some of the words didn't make any sense. I also remember the first version of DOS in my language (the commands was the same but the error messages was translated). For some of the messages I had to translate it back to English to understand the meaning of them.

Comment: Agreed with @klausbyskov. Programming happens in english, period (my native language is German, so no culture imperialism). Also, UTF-8 is 100% backward-compatible with ASCII, so it's not an either-or, it's more "should we allow names that can't be undestood by any programmers except the few that happen to speak this language".

Comment: It's fun watching people attempt to apply logic to what is really just ethnocentrism.

Comment: @JUST:  It isn't really fun watching people making up bad reasons for things that are for good reasons.  Is it ethnocentrism that the control words for music are in Italian, not to mention a lot of the really good operas?  In a given technical field, like programming or music, it's desirable to have a common language.

Comment: Just to add to what David said: In law, biology, medicine and philosophy they use Latin.

Comment: To counter what David Thornley and some said, in law, biology, medicine and philosophy they use Latin **in the West**.  In music they use Italian **in the West**.  David's musical reference is about as ethnocentric as it gets, in fact, not to mention as ignorant about the wider world as it gets.  [Look at all the Italian!](http://chandrakantha.com/tablasite/glossary.htm)  (The "Italian" word you might need to learn there is "abhiman".)  That's one example.  There are **dozens** more.  Just because you don't know of it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  Even in programmming.

Comment: As per sections 2.1 Character Set & 2.3 Identifiers of the Annotated Ada Reference Manual, Ada2005- and Ada2012-compliant compilers permit identifiers to be composed of Unicode characters that are designated as having the "letter, uppercase", "letter, lowercase", "letter, titlecase", "letter, modifier", "letter, other", or "number, letter" properties in the Unicode character database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see from other answers, most modern languages allow this, including Perl, Python, Go, Ruby, Java, C♯, variants of lisp, Fortess, ADA, and many more. C and C++ do not, but those aren’t modern.

Regarding C♯, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx):

> The rules for identifiers given in this section correspond exactly to those recommended by the Unicode Standard Annex 15

---

As for converting an API to a chosen language - this is not feasible. You would require a translator that understands the nuances and meaning of every method, variable and class name and translate those correctly - this is not the same as being able to *use* the characters of a chosen language in code.

Comment: As far as the converting API to another language.  I don't mean to imply automatic machine translation.  Rather, if I was Chinese, I would like to use Boost in conjunction with some standardly accepted *API-skin* that converts the Boost API into Chinese.  This way it would be much easier to learn.  Granted, it would be a little more difficult to talk about with an English speaker, but I think that the API-skin would allow for translation the other direction as well.  Besides, when the average Chinese programmer is talking about programing, he's likely speaking with another Chinese person.

Comment: Not writing code in the language you think/speak of is an advantage IME, as it allows to give technical terms a technical meaning that isn't marred by the regular meaning of the terms, both usually having little more than loose relationship.

Comment: Python does not allow to use unicode variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Ada (among others) allows for internationalized identifiers using UNICODE.

However, my personal opinion is software should be written using a single, universally understandable and sufficiently simple language (English, obviously) to encourage collaboration, ensure understandability and reusability of code.

Comment: Single, universally understandable and sufficiently simple... English scores 0.5 out of 3 there. (0 for single, 0.5 for sufficiently simple)

Comment: @kotlinski: English is the closes to universally understandable (among the most widespread languages, and certainly the most widespread one among tech people - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow has some nice data). And while English *is* complex, *all* natural languages are inherently complex - and English isn't the worst (German grammar, for example, is much larger and has more nasty corner cases).

Comment: @kotlinski This is, sure, subjective. In my opinion, when thinking about languages I know or I learned in the past, the complexity and easyness is like this: English < Netherlands < German < Russian < Czech. Czech is my mother tongue and I respect foreigners that can crunch it. On the other hand, English seems as the simplest. Once I saw an Ada source code written in Chinese… I didn't have a clue what was going on! :-)

Comment: @Ondrej see comment on Oded's answer.  I wonder what your thoughts are.

Answer (score 2):

[Fortress](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community/) makes extensive use of Unicode (perhaps in an [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29)-like way); see http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community/wiki/FeatherweightJava for one example.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi has that feature since Version 2009

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has this feature.

Answer (score 2):

.Net supports Unicode and I'm working with C# Unicode variable everyday.

Answer (score 2):

C#, Java, Python3, as far as I know, are all Unicode based programming.

I found no one above mentioned **Python**, so I added it. Python has a fantasy feature: everything (function, class, module, variable, class instance) is object and every object can attached a document to describe it. This feature may be useful for organizing code and executing script interactively. For example:

```
# Python code in interactive mode
>>> def MyFunc():
    '''This is self-included document.
It can be write in multi lines.'''
    print('foobar')
>>> print(MyFunc.__doc__)
This is self-included document.
It can be write in multi lines.
>>> MyFunc()
foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations of common lisp would allow this. AFAIK the language specification doesn't forbid it or require it (it only requires a basic ASCII character set).

Answer (score 1):

Tcl allows you to use Unicode characters for command and variable names, though it's recommended to avoid them for variable names because the shortcut syntax doesn't cope at the moment (i.e., you'd have to use the form `[set Ω]` instead of `$Ω`).

Answer (score 1):

Scheme, PLT Racket and Lisp Flavored Erlang all allow for unicode identifiers (made simple thanks to prefix syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Swift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)), introduced by Apple in 2014. Here is a code snippet:

var 国 = "美国"

Good Luck with your search for the best one!

Comment: country = America? :P My Kanji is a little rusty.

Comment: It took be a while to read that because `var 國 = "美國"`
国 is simplified for 國 (或 → 玉)

Answer (score 0):

Perl and Go both allow full Unicode identifiers.  Perl requires a `use utf8;` declaration, but Go does this automatically.

See [UAX#31: Unicode Identifier and Pattern Syntax](http://unicode.org/reports/tr31/), for various concerns.

In general, an identifier should match the pattern `^\p{ID_Start}\p{ID_Continue}*$`, although languages are free to add to that. For example, Java adds the currency symbols (`\p{Sc}`), including `$`.